# Is it possible to automatize my Telegram account to share messages from some channels to one?

Tags: bots, telegram

I want to share messages from many channels in Telegram to one channel with my account inside the channel.

Answer (score 0):

You can add **`modir_robot`** as admin of your output channel, then start the bot and follow setting page to add you input channels.